# How to get API data to a separate HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, api, cryptocurrency, coingecko

I'm building a project using coingecko's cryptocurrency api. Currently I have a chart displaying statistics 1-100 of the highest ranking coins. What is the best way to click on the individual coins and load an information page for that specific currency, without backend coding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React, you can use `react-router` and the `useParams()` hooks:

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: Any solutions without react?

Comment: Other Javascript frontend frameworks like Vue and Angular have ways to handle, but the React implementation is straightforward and easy to get going. I can't think of any solutions that don't include a frontend framework or a backend off the top of my head.